# Angular 8 Reactive Forms with reusable child-components example

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, nested-forms

I have created a solution on [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-child-component) using Angular Reactive Forms and child-components.
However, - I get an error, when using **formControlName** on Input elements. Can someone provide an example on how to use Reactive Forms and child-components?

Problem is in **company.component.html**

```
<input type="text" formControlName="companyName">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `formControlName` incorrectly.

`formControlName` is a HTML attribute for a `FormGroup` to interpret as it parses a template and attaches handlers, it doesn't require square brackets `[]`.

This confusion arises often because you use the Angular input tag `[formControl]` to attach a *standalone* FormControl, i.e. `[formControl]="myFormControl"`

In `addresss.component.html` and `company.component.html` you need to change your formControlNames to the format: `formControlName="{{formControlName}}"`

Alternatively, you could create individual FormControls `public StreetNameFormControl = new FormControl('')` in those components and reference them with a format such as: `[formControl]="StreetNameFormControl"`.

**EDIT:** As a side note, from experience, building forms this way will often lead to heartache. It is possible, but unless you really need to break down the form into these sub components, I'd advise not doing it. One problem you will likely face is populating the forms later, say for example if you want to reuse them to **edit** an existing entity. You will have to write custom code to pass values all the way down your components to populate them. On the other hand, if you have them as one `FormGroup`, you have convenience methods such as `patchValue` at your disposal.